# Windows 7 backup size shows 2.27 GB, even though I deleted all of the backups

Tags: windows-7, backup

In Windows 7, after I deleted all of the system images that I backed up,
the backup size shows 2.27 GB.

Also, in the manage space usage summary, the following is displayed:

Data file backup: 0 bytes

System image: 2.33 GB

I also deleted all of the restore points.
The backup location is the D partition.

Why is the backup not empty, and how do I delete it?

Comment: Why are you worried about 2.27GB.  So I can help you, tell me the steps to bring this information up on my own machine, my guess system image cannot be "reset".

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem is. I need to delete shadow copies that are stored on D partition.

Comment: @BlueSky post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I deleted shadow copies on partition D with disk cleanup.